# Adding non-spatial SQLite query to QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, sqlite, dbmanager

How do I load a query of a non-spatial table to be used as a join with a spatial layer? The DB Manager doesn't allow me to load as a layer and I don't want to load the whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DB must have the spatial metadata even if the specific table doesn't have spatial data to be correctly recognized by qgis

Answer (score 7):

There are at least four options: the three options before loading the data as a layer, the last one after the layer is loaded.

### Option 1: Data source Mananger Filter

Use Data Source manager to load data. Before loading a table, click on `Set Filter` at the bottom of the page. Like this, you can filter before loading data. Demonstrated on this screenshot with a PostGIS database, but works the same for SpatiaLite connections:

[image]

### Option 2: DB Manager Query

In DB Manager, click Menu Database > SQL window (or press `F2`). Insert your query and than click to load as a layer:

[image]

See for non spatial tables:

[image]

### Option 3: Browser Panel SQL

Open the database in Browser Panel, right-click the table and select `Execute SQL...`

[image]

### Option 4: Provider Feature Filter

Use [Provider Feature Filter](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder) to only load a selection of all features of the source to QGIS. You can find it in Layer Properties (right click layer) > Source tab. Expand `Provider Feature Filter` and click on `Query Builder`.

Be aware (from [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#query-builder)):

> The filter is made at the data provider (OGR, PostgreSQL, MSSQL…)
> level. So the syntax depends on the data provider (DateTime is for
> instance not supported for the ESRI Shapefile format).

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the idea behind this is to avoid the load of the whole table in the first place. In this method still have to load everything before filtering the data, also this doesn't allow the use of aggregation functions.

Comment: See updated answer, option 1.

Comment: This is really interesting but my database is non-spatial so it is an SQLite DB and not SpatiaLite, that means if I try to connect through Data Source Manager | SpatiLite it gives me a metadata check failed error, with the message **really a SpatiaLite database**?

Comment: And if you confirm it is a SpatialLite db, what happens? In fact, SpatiaLite is an extension to SQLite - so in my undertanding, if you can load a spatial version of SQLite (geometry + data), a non-spatial ("simple": data without geometry) should be possible to load - shouldn't it?

Comment: How do you load your SQLite database/non spatial table to QGIS at all, by the way...?

Comment: If a confirm it doesn't do anything. That's what I thought, but at the moment it seems it isn't possible. There are two options, with the data source provider as a vector, but it doesn't allow queries and the second one is making the connection with the DB manager it allows to do queries with it, but the weird thing is how it doesn't have a geom column, doesn't let me load the query's result as a layer.

Comment: Option 2 should work for non spatial tables as well, see the 2nd screenshot just posted now. This loads as a data table layer in QGIS.

Comment: Thanks. Yes. That was one of the first things that I did and gives me an error. I guess something else must be happening.

Comment: Yes, I guess it is not the lack of possibilities to do what you want, but that the database you use drops an error. You should provide more info. As it is written now, the question is about possibilities to apply an SQL query to load data. As shown, this is possible. So you should focus more on the specific problem in your case, maybe opening a new post.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more option that is supported by GDAL but unfortunately not by QGIS.

It is possible to write a virtual GDAL vector data source than includes a SQL query by following the manual https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html.

A simple example follows. The source layer "foo" contains 3 features but the SQL selects only one.

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="foo">
        <SrcDataSource>onlyattributes.sqlite</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcSQL>SELECT * from foo where bar='test2'</SrcSQL>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

Test with ogrinfo is successful

```
ogrinfo onlyattributes_with_sql_select.vrt -al
INFO: Open of `onlyattributes_with_sql_select.vrt'
      using driver `OGR_VRT' successful.

Layer name: foo
Geometry: None
Feature Count: 1
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
bar: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(foo):0
  bar (String) = test2
```

Unfortunately there seems to be a bug or a missing feature in QGIS and it does not handle the OGR VRT format right. It is possible to select a .vrt file as a new GDAL/OGR vector data source and a new layer appears into QGIS, but it is always empty. The same happens even when the .vrt file contains also geometries.

[image]